# Multiple Select Get Text Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I need to get the text and id in multiple select.

My Html

```
<select multiple="" class="form-control border-input" v-model="newSelectedAccess">
   <option v-for="role in roles" :value="role.id">{{ role.name }}</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Add" style="margin-top: 10px;" @click="moveSelected($event)">
```

My methods:

```
moveSelected(e){
       console.log(this.newSelectedAccess)
      }
```

The output is just an id. I can't get the text.

[image]

Comment: your v-model is bound to newSelectedAccess not to newSelectedRoles,
edit: if you want to get the text and id then you need to set your value attribute for option like this:  `:value="role"`

Comment: You are just passing `role.id` to `:value` thats why you are getting only id, pass the name also like in an object `:value="{name:role.name, id: role.id}"`

Comment: You got it buddy... so easy. It works like a charm... thanks!

Comment: Both idea works... you refined it! Both of you are rockstar! Thanks